# MVC5 Editor Template for List<string>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model with a public property of type List

I would like to create a custom editor for this type.

What I'd like is to have a TextArea where each line is a string in the List.

```
public List<string> myListOfString {get;set;}
```

Just don't know where to start...

It seems pretty simple but can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: A `<textarea>` bind to a single value, not a collection of values. Not sure why you would want to bind a collection to a text area, but you would need to convert your `List<string>` to `string` (each value separated by `Environment.NewLine`) and then when you post, you would need to split the string back into a collection

Answer (score 0):

You could use the UIHint attribute and point to a custom EditorTemplate. Editor templates work like views, so your model would be List. However **I don't think that is a good path**, because you'll need to convert to and from list to text, and that would add logic to presentation layer.

What I would do in this case is create a new ViewModel, where your list is a String. Let the controller handle the conversion from and to String/List.

```
public class Classroom
{
    public int ClassNumber { get; set; }
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    public List<string> Students { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ClassroomViewModel
{

    public int ClassNumber { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string StudentsNames { get; set; }
    ...
}


public class SchoolController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult SomeAction(int classroomId)
    {
       Classroom model = ... // Get the original model from somewhere

       var viewModel = new ClassroomViewModel();
       viewModel.ClassNumber = model.ClassNumber;

       foreach (string item in model.Students)
       {
           viewModel.StudentNames += item + "\n";
       }

       return View(viewModel);
    }

}
```